# VIF using car and olsrr packages in R

Tags: r, regression

I have finished run a regression model and now would like to check the VIF using the car package and have also tried the olsrr package but when I call (libary(car) and library(olsrr) them I keep getting an error and now can not conduct VIF tests:
library(car)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required

library(olsrr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘olsrr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required

Please help on what am I doing wrong and what can I do to get at least one or both packages working so that I can check my regression out VIF

Comment: ok try to uninstall your package, remove.packages("olsrr"), check that you have rlang_0.4.5 installed; then reinstall olsrr

Comment: also I don't know if you have other packages that are loaded and uses this old version of rlang.. in anyway check that you have the 0.4.5 version. I have that and could load olsrr

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the rlang package.

Comment: No, let me try that, I assume i just update it like any other normal package ?